# In Management studio how to import csv into existing table and making datatypes match

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, management-studio-express

I have an already set up table in management studio where all of the datatypes are varchar(50) while a few are varchar(80), I want the ability to delete all the rows in the table and import new data(csv) in using the import wizard, but for some reason it doesnt import because of a truncating error even though the data i am importing is smaller than the datatypes which are in the table

Comment: alter table <tablename> alter column <ColumnNabe> varchar(80)

Answer (score 1):

While copying the data from cav into it is not only necessary to have same datatypes.U should specify same size as of ur data.Like if u have string with 100 characters then u should specify the size of varchar (100) for that column

Comment: so even if you have set up a table with a column as varchar(80) and you are importing in a column with max size of 60, you need to specify the column as varchar(80) before you import